# seleccionar clase con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pues vuelvo a tener un problema inexplicable con jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id=”listado”>
         <ul>
               <li>Renault <button type=”button” class=”btn-remove”>Borrar</button></li>
               <li>Honda <button type=”button” class=”btn-remove”>Borrar</button></li>
               <li>Ford <button type="button" class=”btn-remove”>Borrar</button></li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Simplemente quiero añadirle una función click a la clase btn-remove. Esto es lo que tengo en mi js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.btn-remove').click(function() {
    console.log('entro');
      $(this).parent().remove();
  });

});
```

Si en vez de seleccionar btn-remove selecciono button, me funciona. Pero esto no puede ser porque habrá más botones en mi html.
He probado a seleccionarlo de las siguientes maneras:

```
$('button .btn-remove')
$('li button .btn-remove')
$('ul li button .btn-remove')
$('#listado ul li button .btn-remove')
```

Pero de ninguna manera lo encuentra... ¿Alguien ve el error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código está OK, pero te traiciona el tipo de comillas que estás usando:

Esto no es reconocido: `”btn-remove”` esto sí: `"btn-remove"`.

Por otra parte, considera cargar tus librerías en el `head`, no al final. Y también, renuncia ya de una vez al uso de `$(document).ready(function(){` fue declarado obsoleto en jQuery 3 y quizá lo saquen del núcleo de jQuery 4. Si tienes miles o cientos de archivos con su uso vas a tener problemas cuando quieras usar jQuery 4 en un futuro. Debes cambiarlo por `$( function() {`

```js
$( function() { 

  $('.btn-remove').click(function() {
    console.log('entro');
      $(this).parent().remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div id="listado">
         <ul>
               <li>Renault <button type="button" class="btn-remove">Borrar</button></li>
               <li>Honda <button type="button" class="btn-remove">Borrar</button></li>
               <li>Ford <button type="button" class="btn-remove">Borrar</button></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Me ganaste la respuesta, bien identificadas las comillas, jamás había visto unas dobles invertidas

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob sí, es raro, quizá el editor de código o la configuración del OS le está haciendo una mala jugada. Aunque es raro que un editor de código ponga ese tipo de comillas.

Comment: Pues he copiado y pegado TAL CUAL y sigue sin funcionar. He probado a hacer:

Comment: `  if(".btn-remove"){
    console.log('existo');
  }` y efectivamente me devuelve el log... Estas cosas me desesperan... Seguiré intentándolo o crearé un proyecto nuevo.

Comment: @InfiniteRoads tienes que revisar todas las comillas, en todo el código tenías estas comillas `”` que no son correctas para etiquetar en HTML. Debes cambiarlas todas por `"`.

Comment: Efectivamente. También estaban repartidas por el HTML. Muchas gracias!!